# ssh not using server name in config

Tags: linux, ssh

I try to make a config for connecting to a remote ssh server via the command `ssh <server short name>`. I put this into `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host <server short name> <server full name>
    Host <server full name>
    User <my username on the remote server>
    Port 22022
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
```

I can connect using

```
$ ssh <server full name>
```

but it fails with the command

```
$ ssh <server short name>
ssh: Could not resolve hostname <server short name>: Name or service not known
```

I've checked the spelling several times and I could not find a mistake. Any ideas why the second command fails?

Comment: run the command with verbose logging. And make sure you don't have typo in the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Host` is not as SSH option; it always starts a new section, regardless of indent level. Thus you have two config sections; an empty one matching `<shortname> <fullname>` and then one matching just `<fullname>`.

Instead, the second line needs to be `HostName <fullname>`.

Comment: having same issue as the OP, *except* i just copy/pasted an already working section to give a shortened name for a host that already works (e.g. changed Host value only, already have HostName correct)

Answer (score 1):

See the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)

The `host` keyword is used to group configuration together and can also be used to define an alias for a host or configure multiple hosts at once.

Consider the following scenario:
At work you have two servers, called dev.example.com and test.example.com where you use the same key pair and a github account with a second key pair. You could then setup the following config

```
host *.example.com
identityfile ~/.ssh/work-key
user bob
Port 22022
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11 yes

host github.com
identityfile ~/.ssh/github-key

host dev
hostname dev.example.com

host test
hostname test.example.com
```

And the use something like this to connect:

```
ssh dev
```